# Post data for comment is not being transferred to query

Tags: php, mysql, sql-update

I have a update query that I want to use and it's not working. All data is being posted except for `CommentID` and I can't understand why.

This is my query's output:

```
UPDATE comments SET
    title='PHP',universitet='Högskolan',
    kurs='Objekt orienterad programmering i PHP',
    kurskod='HIG480-34', betyg='8', message='kom igen nu PHP'
WHERE CommentID = ''
```

As you can see `WHERE CommentID = ''` is empty.

```
<?php
require_once 'DBConnection/connection.php';

class EditPost{

    public $comment;
    public $id;


    public function __construct() {
        $this->comment = comment;
        $this->id = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['CommentID']);

    }




    public function EditThePost(){

        if(!isset($_POST['editComment'])){

            $query = "SELECT * FROM comments WHERE CommentID = '$this->id'";
            $result = mysql_query($query);
            $this->comment = mysql_fetch_array($result);


        }elseif(isset($_POST['CommentID'])){

            $updateQuery = "UPDATE comments SET title='$_POST[title]',universitet='$_POST[universitet]',kurs='$_POST[kurs]',kurskod='$_POST[kurskod]',betyg='$_POST[betyg]',message='$_POST[TheComment]' WHERE CommentID = '$_POST['CommentID]'";
            mysql_query($updateQuery) or die(mysql_error());

            echo $updateQuery;
            header("Location: loggedin.php");
            exit();


        }
    }


}
```

Here is the edit page with HTML:

```
<?php
session_start();
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
require_once 'DBConnection/connection.php';
require_once 'Posting/editPost.php';
$edit = new EditPost();
$edit->EditThePost();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="sv">
    <?php include('incl/header.php'); ?>

    <body>

        <!--The Navbar-->
        <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">

            <div class="container" align="center">
                <a href="loggedin.php">Hem</a> ||
                <?php include('incl/logoutUser.php'); ?>
            </div>

        </div>



        <!--The page container-->
        <div id="container" >  
            <img src="logo.png" id="logoType" align="center">
            <br>
            <br>
            <span class="label label-warning">Redigera inlägg:</span>

            <div class="container" align="left">
                <br>
                <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" method="post">

                    <p><span class="label label-info">Titel: </span> <br><input type="text" require name="title" placeholder="Ange titel.." value="<?php echo $edit->comment['title'] ;?>"</p>
                    <p><span class="label label-info">Högskola: </span> <br><input type="text" require name="universitet" placeholder="Ange högskola.." value="<?php echo $edit->comment['universitet']?>"></p>
                    <p><span class="label label-info">Kurs: </span> <br><input type="text" require name="kurs" placeholder="Ange kurs.."  value="<?php echo $edit->comment['kurs']; ?>"></p>
                    <p><span class="label label-info">Kurskod: </span> <br><input type="text" require name="kurskod" placeholder="Ange kurskod.."  value="<?php echo $edit->comment['kurskod']; ?>"></p>
                    <p><span class="label label-info">Betyg: </span> <br><input type="text" require name="betyg" placeholder="Betyg mellan 1-10" value="<?php echo $edit->comment['betyg']; ?>"></p>



                    <p><span class="label label-info">Meddelande: </span></p>
                    <textarea rows="10" cols="80" require name="TheComment" placeholder="Skriv ditt meddelande.." ><?php echo $edit->comment['message'];?></textarea>


                    <br><br>
                    <input type="hidden" name="CommentID" value="<?php echo $_POST['CommentID'];?>"/>
                    <p><input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="editComment" value="Redigera inlägg"></p>
                    <br>
                </form>
                <br />
            </div>
        </div>

        <?php include('incl/footer.php'); ?>

    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Using a class with a deprecated function is redundant. Plus, your code is open to SQL injection. Just use PDO or prepared statements.

Comment: CommentID i the PK i my tabel

Comment: where you create the instance of EditPost?  and pass the params to the constructor?

Comment: Hi Fred!My code is not ready yet.

Comment: Please don't use paste boards if they are integral to the question, since the question will become useless to future readers if the link breaks. We sometimes use pasteboards in the comments for supplementary conversations though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will answer your question while ignoring the security issues, mostly because I don't have much time right now.

You have one issue in your constructor, where you're assigning the contents of a `$_GET['CommentID']` to one variable a the `$_POST['CommentID']`. This is a really bad idea, you should use either `$_GET['CommentID']` or `$_POST['CommentID']`, using both is asking for trouble.

The reason why your comment ID isn't posting is because it's not in your HTML form. From your link, you are doing

```
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $_GET['CommentID'];?>"/>
```

To do what you want, it should read

```
<input type="hidden" name="CommentID" value="<?php echo $_POST['CommentID'];?>"/>
```

Change the `name` attribute of this input to be `CommentID`, read the contents of `$_POST['CommentID']`, and your code should work.

Comment: Thak you very much! It didnt work:( i made the changes that you proposed and its still not sending the CommentID..

Comment: It also looks like you might be getting to this page via a url has `CommentID=:id` in the search string (`$_GET` parameters). If that's the case, you can always do (assuming CommentID is an `int`, take out the casting if it isn't) `$comment_id = isset($_GET['CommentID']) ? (int)$_GET['CommentID'] : (int)$_POST['CommentID'];` and use this value in your form.